# Is it possible to use only ONE 4-to-1 Mux to allow 8 inputs?

Tags: multiplexer

So I am doing some CSE homework where we are told to implement a 3 bit equation using 8-to-1 mux and 4-to-1 muxs only which I understand. What I am wondering however is instead of cascading the muxs to achieve the desired outputs, would it be possible to use only ONE and I emphasize only ONE 4-to-1 MUX to get 8 inputs to work?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "a 3 bit equation"?

Comment: You could have four inputs and four one-hot selects (predecoded selects from 00 01 10 11 to 1000 0100 0010 0001).  I guess this kind of has 8 inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. Only ONE 4-to-1 MUX allows you to select and forward one input from FOUR different, independent inputs. That's it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faFfL6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This may be a trick question, so here's a trick answer.

Of course you can use one 4-to-1 mux IC for eight inputs!

How?

Because they usually come in dual packages, you can't buy one on its own!
[image]

See 74139, 74153, 74155/6 and no doubt several others in the TTL Data Book.

(Separately multiplexing the two outputs is left as an exercise...)